# Tensor flow Load local CSV file

Tags: tensorflow

I am running Tensor flow in a docker container and i am a newbie. This is the code which I just copied from  [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/tflearn/index.html#load-the-iris-csv-data-to-tensorflow) to load CSV dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Data sets
IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TEST,  target_dtype=np.int)
```

Anyways this throws the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datasets'
```

My question is how to load a csv file which i have locally downloaded in my desktop? should be something like this ?

```
IRIS_TRAINING = "C:\Users\priya\Desktop\iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TEST = "C:\Users\priya\Desktop\iris_test.csv"
```

How to load CSV? Any documentation available?

Comment: Both relative and absolute paths should work. So e.g. if you place the data file in the same directory as your python script you can just use `IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"`. Please let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah I just uploaded the data in the Jupyter and used   panda for reading. ipd = pd.read_csv("iris.csv"). It worked!!

Comment: I have the same issue! I install everything properly, but I get AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_csv' , I just want to run the tutorial without using anything else...